# Codeigniter select option view records from mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I've got some troubles with loading db data to an select option form. Records are not showing and I don't know where is a problem.. I need to view 'name' from 'location_cities' table in db.

Controller:

```
public function edit_product($id)
    {
$data['product_location'] = $this->product_model->get_product_location();
$this->load->view('dashboard/includes/_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/product/edit_product', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/includes/_footer');
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_product_location()
    {
      $this->db->join('location_cities');
      $this->db->select('location_cities.*');
      $query = $this->db->get('location_cities');
      return $query->result(); 
    }
```

View:

```
  <select name="product_city" class="select2 form-control">
    <?php
 foreach ($product_location as $row): ?>
 <option value="<?= $row->name; ?>"><?= $row->name; ?></option> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**I would much appreciate your tips how to fix this.**
Kind regards, Krzysztof

Comment: `$this->db->join` needs two arguments and you're passing only one, I think that's causing the error. But in your case you should't need a join at all, just the `$this->db->get` should do. Try removing both of these lines: `$this->db->join('location_cities');` and `$this->db->select('location_cities.*');`

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. unfortunately i did nothing.. maybe problem is with something else :/

Comment: @KrzysztofModrzewski what is the value of this `$data['product_location']` ?